# Emailing with a loop in vba

Tags: vba, email, outlook, email-attachments

I have a sheet of names with the email address for each person. For each person on the list I need to email them a PDF that is named PDFMailer and a PDF that is titled with their last name in all caps.

So my solution was to loop through the list and for each person on the list put together the email in the body of the loop, attach the PDFs and then send it and repeat for a predetermined portion of the sheet of recipients.

```
Sub Emails()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsMedRec As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsMedRec = wb.Sheets("Medical Records")

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

'sets up what is needed to email
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


'length of the sheet with the medical record information
Dim n As Integer
n = wsMedRec.Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Dim upp, lower As Integer
Dim startdoc As Integer

'lets the user decide how long to run the code in case whole sheet is not wanted or needed
lower = InputBox("Enter the starting row number for the email recipients list.")
upp = InputBox("Enter the ending row number for the email recipients list.")

'upper bound cannot exceed the length of the sheet
If upp > n Then

    MsgBox ("You have chosen an upper bound that exceeds the length of your recipients list. End code and try again.")

End If


Dim lastname As String
Dim emailaddr As String
Dim docname, HIPAAname As String


'sends the fax for each row of info
For i = lower To upp

    lastname = wsMedRec.Range("B" & i).Value
    emailaddr = wsMedRec.Range("I" & i).Value


    'puts together the names of the two documents that are going to be faxed
    docname = "PDFMailer.pdf"
    HIPAAname = UCase(lastname) & ".pdf"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = emailaddr
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Body = ""
        .Attachments.Add ("S:\Med Records\Letters\" & docname)     

        .Attachments.Add ("S:\Med Records\HIPAAS\" & HIPAAname)
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

Next


'ends the email server use
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing




End Sub
```

I run the code and it sends the first email just fine with all of the attachments. The code runs for the rest of the iterations of the loop but it does not send any emails at all. It only sends the first one.

Comment: Move `Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)` inside the loop.

Comment: Get rid of `On Error Resume Next` and then resolve to *never* use that until you know that all it does is *prevent you from seeing useful information that would otherwise help you debug the mysterious situations you encounter when you ignore all errors* :)

Comment: Also, what BigBen said. If you're sending emails in a loop, then you need to *create* a new `MailItem` within the loop

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application) article in MSDN.

Try to use the following code:

```
Sub Emails()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsMedRec As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsMedRec = wb.Sheets("Medical Records")

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

'sets up what is needed to email
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'length of the sheet with the medical record information
Dim n As Integer
n = wsMedRec.Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Dim upp, lower As Integer
Dim startdoc As Integer

'lets the user decide how long to run the code in case whole sheet is not wanted or needed
lower = InputBox("Enter the starting row number for the email recipients list.")
upp = InputBox("Enter the ending row number for the email recipients list.")

'upper bound cannot exceed the length of the sheet
If upp > n Then

    MsgBox ("You have chosen an upper bound that exceeds the length of your recipients list. End code and try again.")

End If


Dim lastname As String
Dim emailaddr As String
Dim docname, HIPAAname As String


'sends the fax for each row of info
For i = lower To upp

    lastname = wsMedRec.Range("B" & i).Value
    emailaddr = wsMedRec.Range("I" & i).Value


    'puts together the names of the two documents that are going to be faxed
    docname = "PDFMailer.pdf"
    HIPAAname = UCase(lastname) & ".pdf"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail      
        .To = emailaddr
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Body = ""
        .Attachments.Add ("S:\Med Records\Letters\" & docname)    

        .Attachments.Add ("S:\Med Records\HIPAAS\" & HIPAAname)
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

Next


'ends the email server use
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```